# Laravel Chains of wheres

Tags: laravel

I am working with laravel and making a query with filters, i am not sure how to do that but i have an idea, this is what i want.

```
            $wheresMethodsChain;

            $type = "house";
            $model = "paper";
            // sometimes it could be empty
            $size = "";

            if ($type != "") {
                // add to chain to call later
                add_to_my_chain_of_wheres( $wheresMethodsChain , ->where('type',$type) );
                // wheresMethodsChain = ->where('type',$type)
            }
            if ($model != "") {
                add_to_my_chain_of_wheres( $wheresMethodsChain , ->where('model',$model) );
                // wheresMethodsChain = ->where('type',$type)->where('model',$model)

            }
            if ($size != "") {
                add_to_my_chain_of_wheres( $wheresMethodsChain , ->where('size',$size) );
                // wheresMethodsChain =  ->where('type',$type)->where('model',$model)

            }
            // the final chain should be something like this, only two because the "$size" variable is empty
            // ->where('type',$type)->where('model',$model)

            // Finally add the chain of wheres at the end of my query
            $regs = DB::table('mytable')->paginate(10)->wheresMethodsChain;
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would do that:

```
$query = DB::table('mytable');

if($type){
    $query = $query->where('type', $type);
}
if($model){
    $query = $query->where('model', $model);
}
if($size){
    $query = $query->where('size', $size);
}

$results = $query->paginate(10);
```

Comment: `$query` does not have `where` method, `
    call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Support\Collection' does not have a method 'where'  `

Comment: I have updated my answer. I had `->paginate(10)` in the wrong place.

Comment: Now is working, it is really close to something that i  need, thanks.

Comment: Just a note: you don't need to keep assigning a new `$query` after you initialize it.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution. If you're always going to use the `=` operator like...

```
$query->where('something', $something)
```

Then, you could try something like this:

```
$data = array_filter(compact('type', 'model', 'size'));

$results = DB::table('mytable')->where($data)->paginate(10);
```